# Pandas manual label encoding

Tags: python, pandas

Hello and Happy new year everybody.

I came across some weird behaviour of pandas when  tried to manually encode some labels. It would be awesome if anybody could explain why this is happening.

So here is my code

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
from seaborn import load_dataset as data

titanic  = data('titanic')

# Set a random set s.t. you get the same as i get 
np.random.seed(12345)

# Draw 91 Observations as test 
df_test = titanic.sample(n = 91 )

# Take the remaining as trainings data 
df_train = titanic.drop(df_test.index)

# Delet the old data to free the memory 
del titanic 


# Save references of the data in a list s.t. we can loop over them 
frames = [df_train, df_test] 

# loop over the columns and the dataframes an set them as categorical 

for df in  frames:
    for col in 'sex embarked embark_town alone who'.split():

        # save the destinct values of the training data 
        # HERE IS THE MISTAKE
        uniques = df_train[col].unique() 

        # encode those unique values  numerically 
        for n, uni in enumerate(uniques): 
            df.loc[df[col] == uni , col] = n
```

So my problem is that with this the labels of the `embarked` variable in the testing data does NOT get overwritten.
I get

```
print(df_train.embarked.unique() )
[0 1 2 nan]

print(df_test.embarked.unique()) 
['S' 'Q' 'C']
```

instead of:

```
print(df_train.embarked.unique() )
[0 1 2 nan]

print(df_test.embarked.unique()) 
[0 1 2 ]
```

With a little bit of experimentation i found that the line `uniques = df_train[col].unique()` is the reason why.  If this would be changes to 
`uniques = df[col].unique()`
everything works just fine.

My question is why does this happen since  `df_test`and `df_train`are just two part from the same data, they contain the same label ( even though there might be the chance that one label does not occur in test ) an as such my version should work just fine ( but doesn't).

Thanks in advance.